# How to load js file after html got loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am working on a Template with animations.
Here the thing is, the JS file which is related to animations, should be written at the bottom of the HTML page like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="wide wow-animation" lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Site Title-->
    <title>Sample</title>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400i,700,700i,900,900i">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">            
</head>   
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="abc"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If we write

```
<script src="js/core.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

at the top of the HTML, the animations won't work.

Now, I am developing the AngularJS app by using that template.
Here I couldnt see the animations.

**I am in confusion where to declare those external js files.**

Comment: if they work at the bottom of the page why are you trying to move them to the top?

Comment: you always declare js at end, and css in begin,html needs to load first then js,

Comment: Use `defer` with the script tag to delay script loading

Comment: @Mayank I tried using defer, For plain HTML it is working,
But in AngularJS, It's not working. 
Can you suggest any other ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my issue got fixed, with the below piece of code in the controller

```
myApp.
controller('commonCtrl',['$scope','$http','$window','$location', function($scope,$http,$window,$location) {
    console.log('commonCtrl');
    function includeJs(jsFilePath) {
        var js = document.createElement("script");
        js.type = "text/javascript";
        js.src = jsFilePath;
        document.body.appendChild(js);
    }
    includeJs("js/core.min.js");
    includeJs("js/script.js");
}]);
```

Here JS files are loading, at the end, So no issues. All animations got working

Answer (score 4):

You can use javascript defer ,this attribute tells the browser to only execute the script file once the HTML document has been fully parsed and loaded

```
<script defer src="script.js">
```

Browser support , https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

`NOTE: defer attribute should be used with an external javascript file`

Comment: I tried using defer, For plain HTML it is working,
But in AngularJS, It's not working. 
Can you suggest any other ideas

Answer (score 2):

Because no one explained *why*, you should know that HTML is parsed **synchronously**. This means that the browser "reads" the file one line at a time, starting from the top and working it's way to the bottom.

So when your script is declared at the top of the page, it is loaded before any actual HTML has been loaded. If your script depends on HTML to exist then your script will fail. The easiest, and best way to avoid this is to simply declare those scripts before your closing `</body>`. As other's mentioned, you can also use the `defer` tag, though it should be noted that this does not work for inline Javascript, and isn't supported in older browsers.

Comment: I tried using defer, For plain HTML it is working,
But in AngularJS, It's not working. 
Can you suggest any other ideas